# Zend 2.2 adding new module, page goes blank

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am new to Zend Framework and trying to setup my first module.

Installation goes fine. Everything runs fine i.e. home page and Application module.

Now, Followed all the steps to create Album module but as soon as I add 'Album' module in `application.config.php` it all goes blank. Home page goes blank as well.

Below is the code I have added.

```
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'Application',
        'ZendDeveloperTools',
        'BjyProfiler',
        'User',
        'Album',
    ),
```

Can anyone let me know, what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you add the Album module name to the config, the system will attempt to load that module, if any problem exists with that module's base class, it will cause the system to fail with an error. If you have errors turned off then you will not see it, but instead will be presented with a white screen.

1. check you have errors turned on (error_reporting etc)
2. make sure you have a class called Module in the Album Namespace.
3. make sure the Album\Module class is in the module\album\Module.php file
4. make sure that the code in the Album\Module class does not have any errors in the getConfig method or onBootstrap (if you've added either of those)

Unfortunately without further information on how the module is set up, there is little more we can do to help.

Comment: Ok I will dig in more.. Will come back if anything. Thank you